# VBA Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found

Tags: windows, vba

I know this is a well known error but I event can't find a solution which is working for me...

Last friday I updated my windows and since after this update I can't run VBA macros. (Doesn't matter which macro)
I already googled for this problem and found serveral solutions.

I tried:

- Delete .exd files
- Checked references at Tools->References (No missing references...)
- Installed hotfixes from previous updates which caused this error
- Office repair

Do you have any idea about how to fix this? I don't know what I should do now.

Most of the time I get this error:
**Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found**

Sometimes I got this:
- **Error with the execution of a macro or wizard VBA encountered an error while compiling.**
- **An error occurs in macro. Module: Run Error with the execution of a macro or wizard**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you reviewed this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2009/06/04/visual-basic-6-controls-stop-working-after-security-advisory-960715/

Comment: Have you tried the office repair/re-install.

Comment: I will review this post @Zedee.Chen and currently i am trying the repair function of office. I will give you an update if it helped me and edit my post

Comment: The office repair suite didn't made it working :(